# Validate whether Google API Client's OAuth2 access token is still valid before using it

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

Starting from the point where an user has given permissions to the app, and the access token is stored in session. Following [Google's web server app](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app) example, I'm just checking whether an access token **exist**.

However, the token might expire, or the user might remove it manually on his account page. How do I check that the token is still valid, before executing a request?

Or maybe that approach is wrong, and the correct design includes that I should handle the error **after** executing the action, and *if it's an authorization error* then show the user a way to authorize it once again?

Answer (score 0):

The latter is the recommended approach. By assuming failure and dealing with it routinely, your app is much more robust. The only downside is that an access attempt takes a bit longer because of the need to fetch a new Access Token and retry. If that's a problem (it shouldn't be normally), then you can always note the expiration time of the new Access Token and set up a background process to renew it with say 5 minutes to spare.